# Deleted the LFS objects from GitLab repository however storage space still not freed up

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I have a GitLab repository, and using the feature branch, **remove-lfs** I pushed some LFS objects after running these commands in the same order

```
git lfs install
git lfs track "lfs/*.mp4"
git add .
```

and then commit and push that I later deleted them (including **.gitattributes** file) with the below commands:-

```
git filter-repo --force --path lfs/ --invert-paths
```

My LFS files got deleted successfully from the Gitlab remote repository however the space occupied by LFS objects is still not freed up as shown in this screenshot below even after running below commands:-

```
git push --force --all origin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push -u origin --tags -f
```

[image]

How to regain the space occupied by deleted LFS objects?

Comment: The repository on the server still holds the data of big files in the history. The data are reachable from internal refs which are not for common users. If you make a new clone and check the size of `.git`, you'll find it gets smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed these steps and it worked for me:-

Install `git-filter-repo` first and follow the steps below to clear the unwanted LFS:-

```
git filter-repo --force --path /lfs_dir --invert-paths
```

assuming your LFS are inside the directory (/lfs_dir) or modify the above command to point to right directory of LFS that needs to be removed

Then, remove the lines of unwanted LFS from `.gitattributes` file, and then execute following commands

```
git add .
git commit -m <commit message>
git push --force --all origin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Go to GitLab → Project Repository Settings → General → Advanced and click on ‘Prune unreachable objects’ to prune them now manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should use (on the server side) the prune option of **git lfs**:

```bash
git lfs prune --dry-run --verbose
```

If all is ok for you:

```bash
git lfs prune --verbose
```

By the way, about Gitlab, there is a [discussion here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17711) about the same issue.

Comment: what do you mean by running the git lfs prune on server side? It is unclear